# Sharepoint list custom JSON view not showing correctly in list web-part

Tags: css, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have a custom JSON list view that is displayed correctly as a list, but is not keeping its formatting in list web-part. It was ok a couple of weeks ago when I created it but something changed (maybe a Sharepoint update?)

[This is how it looks as list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdVEw.png)

[And this is how it looks in web-part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay7Li.png)

I would like to make it more compact in web-part and without header.

Here is my JSON code, which worked correctly a couple of weeks ago. Now it seems that hideColumnHeader and height tags are ignored in web-part

```css
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-field-fontSize14  ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary ms-fontColor-red--hover",
      "href": "[$Link]"
    },
    "style": {
      "text-decoration": "none",
      "width": "300px",
      "min-width": "200px",
      "min-height": "1em",
      "height": "1em",
      "white-space": "nowrap",
      "padding-left": "=if(indexOf(@currentField, ' ') == 1, '', if(indexOf(@currentField, ' ') == 3, '20px', '40px'))"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using SharePoint Online, modern experience. Any help in fixing this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a bug from Microsoft, it was fixed today on our tenant.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we can add the following CSS style into **[modern script editor webpart](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)** to hide the columns header.

```
<style>
.ms-DetailsList-headerWrapper{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Or inject custom css using the solution below.

[SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)

Comment: I don't have the Modern Script Editor and don't think I have rights to add it :(

Comment: You can also use SPFx application customiser to inject the CSS to achieve it.